# Regex match any character for any line until we reach a certain match

Tags: .net, regex

I'm currently trying to match with this regex:

```
^(?<Date>(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[/.](19|20)\d\d) (?<Time>(?:(?:(\d+):)?(\d+):)?(\d+)): (?<Name>.*) (?<IP>\([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?\)) (?<GUID>.*) - (?<Line>#([0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)) (?<Code>.*)\n(?<Code2>(\n|.)*)
```

With this as the input:

```
08.08.2012 01:47:40: ferngully (98.169.247.118:2304) 6ff0e06c6d5434a953b2780f852bf762 - #17 "moveIn", 
"land", 
"addWPCur", 
"animate", 
"setDate", 
"playmusic", 
"playsound", 
"switchmove", 

08.08.2012 01:47:40: Thugnificent (72.86.3.240:50218) 696089009a4e885fe5ec0323d4537253 - #0 f)')};
                                        BIS_ALICE_fnc_houseEffects = compile preprocessFileLineNumbers '\ca\modules\alice\d
08.08.2012 01:36:28: [SOER]MrWolf (58.110.48.174:2304) 464f91fcefe7f1014979c5140a0f1649 - #12 airing..."] call d_fnc_VehicleChat};
_object setDamage 0;
sleep d_reload_time_factor;
if (!alive _ob
```

This issue is that it returns only 1 match, it needs to be able to match that as 3 matches.

The goal at the end is to be able to pull the code in between each of those "headers" which include the date, time, name, ip, guid, line and then the multiline code.

**EDIT:**

I resolved the issue, I need to use a look ahead on the second date.

Current regex:

```
^(?<Date>(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[/.](19|20)\d\d?) (?<Time>(?:(?:(\d+):)?(\d+):)?(\d+)?): (?<Name>.*?) (?<IP>\([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:.*?\)?) (?<GUID>[0-9a-z]{32}?) - (?<Line>#[0-9]*?) (?<Code>(\n|.)*?)(?=(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[/.](19|20)\d\d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be your various uses of `.*`. This will match as much as it possibly can (greedy matching). So in this case `Name` (I think) will keep matching until just before the IP in the last entry.

To make the match non-greedy use `.*?`. This tells it to use as little as possible to make the match. This will ensure that it won't try to gobble up entire entries while matching.

Comment: Unless he explicitly sets the `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag, this is not true because the dot does not match newline characters by default.

Comment: This is true. I was forgetting about that sort of thing. Still, he might have that set so it might be helpful. :)

Comment: This is the simplest and most elegant way to search for an exact string in a multi-line string search until that match is found.

Answer (score 1):

Which method are you using? I suspect you are using Regex.Match()

You have this possibilities:

1. [Regex.Match()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c)

   > Searches the specified input string for the first occurrence of the regular expression specified in the Regex constructor.

   Returns a [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match) object. You can get the next match my using [Match.NextMatch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch)
2. [Regex.Matches()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3)

   > Searches the specified input string for all occurrences of a regular expression.

   Returns a [MatchCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection) containing all found matches as [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match) objects

Comment: Good guess, although that alone will not be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the regex using `RegexOptions.Multiline` to allow the `^` to match the start of each line and not just the start of the string.

Or you can add `(?m)` at the start of the regex if you're not using a precompiled regex.

And of course you need to use the correct method for matching regexes (see @stema's answer).